# How to verify if I am subscribed or not and execute an action? in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to execute an action if I am subscribed to a YouTube channel or another if I am not

I know that the path of the button without being subscribed is this

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"subscribe-button\"]/ytd-subscribe-button-renderer/paper-button/yt-formatted-string")).Click();
```

**I have written this pseudocode so that they understand better**

```
If button subscribe is enabled
click on subscribe
else (If I am subscribed)
continue with the code normally
```

Before Subscribe:

[image]

```html
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer">Subscribe <span class="deemphasize style-scope yt-formatted-string">157K</span></yt-formatted-string>
```

```html
<paper-button noink="" class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" aria-disabled="false" elevation="0" aria-label="Subscribe to EminemMusic.">
      <yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer">Subscribe <span class="deemphasize style-scope yt-formatted-string">37M</span></yt-formatted-string>
    <paper-ripple class="style-scope paper-button">


    <div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
    <div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
  </paper-ripple></paper-button>
```

After Subscribe:

[image]

```html
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer">Subscribed <span class="deemphasize style-scope yt-formatted-string">157K</span></yt-formatted-string>
```

```html
<paper-button noink="" class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" aria-disabled="false" elevation="0" aria-label="Unsubscribe from EminemMusic." subscribed="">
      <yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer">Subscribed <span class="deemphasize style-scope yt-formatted-string">37M</span></yt-formatted-string>
    <paper-ripple class="style-scope paper-button">


    <div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
    <div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
  </paper-ripple></paper-button>
```

But how do I verify if it is already subscribed?

*I do not speak English, sorry if I write badly.*

Comment: Does the `Subscribe` button disabled if you are already subscribed? If yes, then you can check the button status as verification of the subscription.

Comment: @supputuri the button changes to gray https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEJdS.png

Comment: Can't you just check the text of the button?

Comment: I tried with `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Subscribe")).Click();` but no found

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant HTML of the SUBSCRIBE and SUBSCRIBED buttons.

Comment: Done, I've already edited the publication.

Comment: I need help, I keep trying but I can not do the code.

Comment: @Gexur check my updated answer and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution. (Took the aria label as base because the aria-label starts with `Subscribe to` when not subscribed, if already subscribed it will be `Unsubscribe from`.

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//paper-button[contains(@aria-label,'Subscribe to')]")).size() > 0){
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//paper-button[contains(@aria-label,'Subscribe to')]")).click();
}
```

You dont need the else as you will continue the script if already subscribed or subscribed as part of above step.

Comment: @supputuri Hello, thanks for helping me. When I place the code, I receive this IWebElement warning that does not contain a definition of 'Size'.

Comment: Try with "Count" or "Size" without the '()'

Comment: Works, but the code after "if" he skip if `(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//paper-button[contains(@aria-label,'Suscribirme a')]")).Count > 0)
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//paper-button[contains(@aria-label,'Suscribirme a')]")).Click();
                }
 //code after if skips` :S

Comment: @Gexur Sorry I did not get your commnet, Do you mean the code after `if{}` not running?

Comment: yes, https://i.imgur.com/1tvPtik.png after the if do not run the "blue" part  and goes straight to the orange color line. (see image to understand)

Comment: wrapp the 'blue' part in the `else` part.

Comment: I need it to work regardless of whether it is `true` or `false`. without `else`

Comment: I changed  `driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindow);` for `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());` and works fine, thanks for the help!, and sorry for my english xD

Comment: No worries, Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the button text.

```
if (subscribeBtn.Text.ToUpper().Contains("SUBSCRIBE"))
{
    subscribeBtn.Click();
}//else
//{
//    Your code here
//}
```

Hope it helps.